# Swift- Buttons on ScrollView in CustomCell overlapping each other

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, tableview

I have created a custom cell in the storyboard, and added a ScrollView in it.
Now, what I want to do is, create multiple buttons based on the data from my webservice. Below is the code for that:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: MainTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = self.postsData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as? String
    let imageurl = self.postsData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("image") as? String
    cell.titleImage.load(imageurl!)

    let jsonStringAsArray = self.postsData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("links")
    let data: NSData = jsonStringAsArray!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let anyObj: AnyObject? = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    var yCoord:CGFloat = 15.0, xCoord:CGFloat = 0.0, buttonHeight:CGFloat = 30.0, buttonWidth:CGFloat = 100.0, buffer:CGFloat = 10.0,i = 0;

    while i<anyObj?.count {
        if cell.viewWithTag((indexPath.row+1)*1000+(i+1)) != nil{
            print("fake")

        }
        else{
            let button :UIButton = UIButton()
            button.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)


            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-Medium", size: 17)
            button.tag = (indexPath.row+1)*1000+(i+1);
            print(button.tag)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.linkButtonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            button.setTitle(anyObj?.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("title") as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.sizeToFit()
            let tempWidth = button.frame.size.width + 10;
            button.frame=CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, tempWidth, buttonHeight)

            cell.buttonScrollView.addSubview(button)


            xCoord += button.frame.size.width + buffer;

        }
        i += 1
    }
    cell.buttonScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xCoord, buttonHeight+10)

    cell.clipsToBounds = true;

    return cell
}
```

The code I have written, seems to work perfectly, except the problem is that buttons in the first and the last cell are overlapped with buttons from the other cells.

The first cell displays all buttons perfectly at first, but when I scroll down to the bottom and come back up, its all messed up.

It is supposed to appear like this on all cells:
[image: The Second cell]

But appears like this:

[image: the fist cell]

I tried checking for views with same tags in the cell, and clipsToBounds, as you can see in the code, but nothing worked for me.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: second screen overlapping button before scrolling or after scrolling screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is adding the button subviews to a cell that was already configured. You will need to remove existing buttons from the cell after you `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` and re-create them again.

Comment: You mean recreate the items that I used from the storyboard too? I am only dynamically creating the buttons in the cell

Comment: No, just re-create the buttons. Your add all of those buttons to a cell, then reuse that cell and the buttons will still be there. You have a check for that tag but the buttons you added for that cell were added for a different row and have non-matching tags. The tags make me sad though, add a property for the custom cell to keep an array and clear that out on reuse.

Comment: Okay, I can remove the buttons using removeFromSuperview() and then recreate them.
But I am too much of a beginner to implement what you said regarding the property for a custom cell.

Comment: In the `MainTableViewCell` class, create a property `var buttons = [UIButton]()`. When you add a button, instead of adding a silly tag, just do `cell.buttons.push(button);` After you dequeue a cell, loop through the cell.buttons and removeFromSuperview.

Comment: Thanks! removeFromSuperView solved it! Will now implement the property and try my luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

your code see me:
your code write button code else but if condition does not any button related code.

Try my adviser of you also write code in if condition in opposite of else condition. after check some time you are not erase you else condition code that you are scrolling you controller that item is overlapping that write erase code button in if condition.